# Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'y': expected 'r/R' or 'a/A'

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am new to neo4j and trying to get data from Postgres table in neo4j. Using the example query given [here](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_load_jdbc_examples), I am trying to run a simple query of getting count of the rows -

```
with "jdbc:postgresql://HOSTurl:5000/MYdb?user=ankit" as url
cypher CALL apoc.load.jdbc(url,"ankit.tablename") YIELD row
RETURN count(*);
```

It is giving me the error -

**Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError**

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'y': expected 'r/R' or 'a/A' (line 2, column 2 (offset: 66))
"cypher CALL apoc.load.jdbc(url,"ankit.tablename") YIELD row"
  ^
```

I don't understand how the error can be in character 'y' in the word *cypher*? Please tell me what is the problem and how to remove that.

Thanks!

Comment: The word `cypher` before `CALL` is unnecessary, take it off.

Comment: @stdob-- Thanks. It worked. But why is it given in the example query?

Comment: I think that this is a mistake in the documentation.

Comment: FYI I have done the pull request : https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/compare/3.4...sim51:patch-1